# addEventListener not working when i import modules in the same javascript from electron

Tags: javascript, electron

i load it from tasks.html with

```
<script  src = "Tasks.js"></script>
```

the buttons do nothing when i import any module but when i remove them it works, i dont think it goes to the function when theres modules cause 323 doesnt print either

buttons do nothing when i have this

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow

apple();



function apple(){

console.log("323")



document.getElementById("profileButton").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    document.getElementById("text").innerText = "64565"; 
})

document.getElementById("tasksButton").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    document.getElementById("text").innerText = "545224"; 
})



}
```

but when i remove the requires it prints and the buttons work

```
apple();



function apple(){

console.log("323")



document.getElementById("profileButton").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    document.getElementById("text").innerText = "64565"; 
})

document.getElementById("tasksButton").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    document.getElementById("text").innerText = "545224"; 
})



}
```

Comment: You run this with `nodejs` or on `broswer`? if it's on browser you can't use `require`...

Comment: visual studio code with npm start